# How to parse string to XML in curl using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, curl

I want to parse simple text into XML format. I tried lots of thing to do it but I am not able to do it.

I have tried below code:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $url = "https:myURL";
    $data = array("username" => "USERID");
    //$ctype = array("Content-Type" => "text/xml");
    $this->curl->create($url);
    //$this->curl->http_header("Content-Type", "application/xml");
    $this->curl->http_header("Accept", "application/xml");
    //$this->curl->http_header("charset", "UTF-8");
    $this->curl->option(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: 
    application/xml-dtd'));
    $this->curl->post($data);
    $xml = $this->curl->execute();
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    print_r($xml);
    exit;
    $this->load->view('home_view');
}
}
```

I am getting this output after running this code.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [responseId] => 290 [status] => SUCCESS [result] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [seed] => 426477071456611 ) )
```

but my requirement is something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response>
   <responseId>246</responseId>
   <status>SUCCESS</status>
<result>
    <seed>292174305068328</seed>
</result>
</response>
```

How can I get this output?

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->output->set_content_type('text/xml', 'UTF-8');    
print($xml);
```

Comment: i am getting this error : Call to a member function asXML() on string